# How can I pass variables to main view in phalconphp

Tags: php, phalcon

How can I pass variables to main view, not just the view for controller.

in fact I want to share a piece of data across all views. how can I do that in phalcon.

for instance, in Laravel, I can use:

`View::share('variable', $value);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a service for that - if this is simple variable it will be an overkill but it will work.

```
<?php 
    // In your bootstrap file
    $di->setShared('variable', 41);
?>
```

Then in any view (or a controller or any DI injectable) it will be avaiable as `$this->variable`. Ie:

```
// some view
<?php echo $this->variable; ?>

// or using volt
{{ variable }}
```

The variable of course can be an object. Personally for such simple variables I'm using config object, ie: `{{ config.facebook.fbId }}`.

Comment: This is a great answer, but there is a syntax error. To create a service in PhalconPHP the second param has to be a function, like this:

$di->setShared('variable', function(){
    return 41;
});

Answer (score 4):

With Phalcon you don't need any additional functions to pass data into the layout. All variables assigned in the action are available in the layout automatically:

**Controller:**

```
class IndexController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->bg    = 'green';
        $this->view->hello = 'world';
    }
}
```

**Main layout:**

```
<html>
<body style="background: <?php echo $bg ?>">

    <?php echo $this->getContent(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Action view:**

```
<div>
    <?php echo $hello ?>
</div>
```

You will see text 'world' on the green background.

Comment: this is equivalent to `$this->view->setVar('x',$x);`. this only set x for current view, I want to have variable across all views, it's not related to any Controller.

Answer (score 3):

I think better would be to create BaseController - parent controller everyone extends. And then using event add shared data to view after execution of each action:

```
<?php

class ControllerBase extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
    protected $_sharedData = [];

    public function initialize()
    {

      // set shared data for all actions
      this->_sharedData = [
         'sharedVar' = 1,
         'overrideMe' = false
      ];
    }

    public function afterExecuteRoute($dispatcher)
    {
        // Executed after every found action
        $this->view->setVar('sharedData', $this->_sharedData);
    }
}
```

In child controller

```
<?php

class IndexController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        // override shared variable for all Index actions
        $this->_sharedData['overrideMe'] = true;
    }

    public function homeAction()
    {
        // add custom variable to shared data
        $this->_sharedData['customVar'] = -1;
    }
}
```